# entity framework mapping fluent api seperate entity map

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to separate my entity map but when do that no changes applied on DB. Why?

Following is my code :

```
//class for example 
 class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("User");
        this.HasKey<int>(p => p.Id);
        this.Property(u => u.UserPin).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(2000);
    }
}
//my project context
 public class ProjectDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnectionString")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
//inject my user map rules 
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());

    }
}
```

How to inject my map configuration to apply?

Comment: what do you mean by *How inject my map configuration to apply*? You have already added configuration using `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());`. Do you mean that database does not reflect changes? If so, you should read about migration.

Comment: yes i mean that database does not reflect changes and type command update-database in package console but no changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as shown below.You have missed the `public` key word :D

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("User");
        this.HasKey<int>(p => p.Id);
        this.Property(u => u.UserPin).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(2000);
    }
}
```